# Angular JS add class name to all table tr and th that have ng-model value

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

User enters number into form field and some calculations are made. I want any element that has a change in the background to add class so I can to show background color change so user can easily see what values are updating as a result of their input.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset=utf-8 />
 <title></title>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var customInterpolationApp = angular.module('calculator', []);

  customInterpolationApp.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('}]}');
  });


  customInterpolationApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [{
      name: 'Misko',
      title: 'Angular creator'
    }, {
      name: 'Igor',
      title: 'Meetup master'
    }, {
      name: 'Vojta',
      title: 'All-around superhero'
    }

  ];
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
 

<div ng-app="calculator" ng-controller='myCtrl'>

 <label for="calculator">Number</label>
 <input type="number" class="form-control" id="calculator" ng-model="number" required>

 <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
           <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Lbs of Product Needed</th>
                <th>Gallons of Product Needed</th>
                <th>Nitrogen</th>
                <th>Phosphorus</th>
                <th>Potassium</th>
                <th>Sulfur</th>
                <th>Calcium</th>
           </tr>
           <tr>
                <td>Urea</td>
                <td>{[{ (+number) / .46 | number:2 }]}</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>{[{ (+number) * .46 | number:2 }]}</td>
                <td>0.00</td>
                <td>0.00</td>
                <td>0.00</td>
                <td>0.00</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
                <td>Ammonium Sulfate</td>
                <td>{[{ (+number) / .21 | number:2 }]}</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>{[{ (+number) * .21 | number:2 }]}</td>
                <td>0.00</td>
                <td>0.00</td>
                <td>{[{ (+number) / .21 * .12 | number:2 }]}</td>
                <td>0.00</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
                <td>Calcium Nitate</td>
                <td>{[{ (+number) / .155 | number:2 }]}</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>{[{ (+number) * .155 | number:2 }]}</td>
                <td>0.00</td>
                <td>0.00</td>
                <td>0.00</td>
                <td>{[{ (+number) / .155 * .17 | number:2 }]}</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
                <td>UN32</td>
                <td>{[{ (+number) / .32 | number:2 }]}</td>
                <td>{[{ (+number) / .32 / 11.06 | number:2 }]}</td>
                <td>{[{ (+number) * .32 | number:2 }]}</td>
                <td>0.00</td>
                <td>0.00</td>
                <td>0.00</td>
                <td>0.00</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
                <td>CAN 17</td>
                <td>{[{ (+number) / .17 | number:2 }]}</td>
                <td>{[{ (+number) / .17 / 12.2 | number:2 }]}</td>
                <td>{[{ (+number) * .17 | number:2 }]}</td>
                <td>0.00</td>
                <td>0.00</td>
                <td>0.00</td>
                <td>{[{ (+number) / .17 * .12 | number:2 }]}</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
                <td>Aqua</td>
                <td>{[{ (+number) / .20 | number:2 }]}</td>
                <td>{[{ (+number) / .20 / 7.58 | number:2 }]}</td>
                <td>{[{ (+number) * .20 | number:2 }]}</td>
                <td>0.00</td>
                <td>0.00</td>
                <td>0.00</td>
                <td>0.00</td>
           </tr>
        </table>
  </div>
 </div>

<div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to create a custom directive that can do the binding for you, but also set a class on the element if the value changes and then remove it after a short delay.

I have written you just such a directive, `bind-and-highlight` (name might need improvement), below and modified your snippet to work with it.

Note that you can also pass in additional attributes of `highlight-class` and `highlight-duration` to modify the class name and duration on a per element basis. By default, it uses a class of `value-changed` and `200ms` as the duration.

Finally, CSS3 transitions are used to create the fade effect.

```js
angular.module('calculator').directive('bindAndHighlight', ['$timeout',
  function($timeout) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: false,
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        var timeoutPromise;

        var highlightClass = attrs.highlightClass || 'value-changed',
          highlightDuration = parseInt(attrs.highlightDuration || '200', 10);

        var unwatch = scope.$watch(attrs.bindAndHighlight, function(newVal, oldVal) {
          elem.text(newVal);
          if (newVal !== oldVal) {
            if (timeoutPromise) {
              $timeout.cancel(timeoutPromise);
            }
            elem.addClass(highlightClass);
            timeoutPromise = $timeout(function() {
              elem.removeClass(highlightClass);
            }, highlightDuration, false /* don't run $scope.$apply(), it isn't needed */ );
          }
        });

        var off = scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
          off();
          unwatch();
          if (timeoutPromise) {
            $timeout.cancel(timeoutPromise);
          }
        });
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

```css
[bind-and-highlight] {
  transition: background-color 200ms;
}
.value-changed {
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title></title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var customInterpolationApp = angular.module('calculator', []);

    customInterpolationApp.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
      $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{');
      $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('}]}');
    });


    customInterpolationApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.items = [{
          name: 'Misko',
          title: 'Angular creator'
        }, {
          name: 'Igor',
          title: 'Meetup master'
        }, {
          name: 'Vojta',
          title: 'All-around superhero'
        }

      ];
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>


  <div ng-app="calculator" ng-controller='myCtrl'>

    <label for="calculator">Number</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="calculator" ng-model="number" required>

    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>Lbs of Product Needed</th>
          <th>Gallons of Product Needed</th>
          <th>Nitrogen</th>
          <th>Phosphorus</th>
          <th>Potassium</th>
          <th>Sulfur</th>
          <th>Calcium</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Urea</td>
          <td bind-and-highlight="(+number) / .46 | number:2"></td>
          <td></td>
          <td bind-and-highlight="(+number) * .46 | number:2"></td>
          <td>0.00</td>
          <td>0.00</td>
          <td>0.00</td>
          <td>0.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ammonium Sulfate</td>
          <td bind-and-highlight="(+number) / .21 | number:2"></td>
          <td></td>
          <td bind-and-highlight="(+number) * .21 | number:2"></td>
          <td>0.00</td>
          <td>0.00</td>
          <td bind-and-highlight="(+number) / .21 * .12 | number:2 "></td>
          <td>0.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Calcium Nitate</td>
          <td bind-and-highlight="(+number) / .155 | number:2 "></td>
          <td></td>
          <td bind-and-highlight="(+number) * .155 | number:2 "></td>
          <td>0.00</td>
          <td>0.00</td>
          <td>0.00</td>
          <td bind-and-highlight="(+number) / .155 * .17 | number:2 "></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>UN32</td>
          <td bind-and-highlight="(+number) / .32 | number:2 "></td>
          <td bind-and-highlight="(+number) / .32 / 11.06 | number:2 "></td>
          <td bind-and-highlight="(+number) * .32 | number:2 "></td>
          <td>0.00</td>
          <td>0.00</td>
          <td>0.00</td>
          <td>0.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>CAN 17</td>
          <td bind-and-highlight="(+number) / .17 | number:2 "></td>
          <td bind-and-highlight="(+number) / .17 / 12.2 | number:2 "></td>
          <td bind-and-highlight="(+number) * .17 | number:2 "></td>
          <td>0.00</td>
          <td>0.00</td>
          <td>0.00</td>
          <td bind-and-highlight="(+number) / .17 * .12 | number:2 "></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Aqua</td>
          <td bind-and-highlight="(+number) / .20 | number:2 "></td>
          <td bind-and-highlight="(+number) / .20 / 7.58 | number:2 "></td>
          <td bind-and-highlight="(+number) * .20 | number:2 "></td>
          <td>0.00</td>
          <td>0.00</td>
          <td>0.00</td>
          <td>0.00</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

On a simple level can use `ng-class` and store copy of original model and use that as reference to current model

```
$scope.model ={
   number:null
}
// create copy
$scope.original = angular.copy($scope.model);
```

then in view

```
<td ng-class="{highlight: original.number !== model.number}">
      {[{ (+model.number) / .21 | number:2 }]}
</td>
```